# How to handle deletion of transaction from transaction tables

Tags: sql

I am allowing my users to remove transactions. e.g. They can remove a transaction which they entered against a particular bill.

How to handle deletion of transaction from transaction tables

1) should i use a boolean field to indicate active/inactive and make this field inactive when user wants to delete a transaction
2) delete transaction permanently from the table

Architecture wise whats better???

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Coming from programming in a financial setting. I can tell you that most companies I make software for like to keep records of everything they've ever done for auditing purposes.

I've seem them use a field like what you describe to show inactivity, in fact I think that is the most common way I've seen it done. Another method would be transferring the record to a (deleted transaction) table using a back-end process.

Key Point:  Permanent deletion is not something I would suggest.